# docker compose - add python to LAMP

Tags: php, python, docker, docker-compose, lamp

In linux I build a blog application that is based on mysql, apache2 and php. But I use some python for it. The python is for adapting python Pygments that is described there https://davidwalsh.name/pygments-php-wordpress .

I prepared docker compose stage that works fine but python does not work in it. How to add python to docker compose?

Here are my files:

```
root@debian:/usr/local/share/a22php7m55# cat docker-compose.yml 
version: "2.1"

services:
    apachephp:
        build: ./a22php7/
        ports:
            - 8888:80
        volumes:
            - "/etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro"
            - "/etc/group:/etc/group:ro"
            - "${PROJECT_ROOT}:/var/www/html"
        networks:
            - database
            - server
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        container_name: ap47


    mysql:
        image: mariadb:5.5
        volumes:
            - ${MYSQL_DATA}:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - database
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: "${MYSQL_NAME}"
            MYSQL_USER: "${MYSQL_USERNAME}"
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
        container_name: maria47

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        networks:
            - database
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: mysql
        container_name: pma47

volumes:
    mariadb:

networks:
    database:
    server:

root@debian:/usr/local/share/a22php7m55# cat a22php7/
```

---

```
root@debian:/usr/local/share/a22php7m55# cat a22php7/Dockerfile 
FROM php:7.1.3-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
root@debian:/usr/local/share/a22php7m55#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the base image for [php:7.1.3-apache](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/7.1/apache/Dockerfile) we see it's built on debian:jessie so we can install python, pip and pygments by adding these lines to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python python-pip
RUN pip install pygments
```